# if condition always false despite the condition being true upon manual execution

Tags: centos, case

I wish to search for a string `mongo` and not starting with comment i.e `#` in a file.

```
homedir=`ls -d ~`

echo "$homedir"

if [[ `cat $homedir/2_need_softwares.txt | grep -v '^#' | grep -iq mongo` ]]; then

echo "Installing mongodb"

else

echo "skipping mongo"

fi
```

Output:

```
/root
skipping mongo
```

I'm on `centos 9`

```
$ uname -a
Linux DKERP 5.14.0-134.el9.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 21 12:57:06 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

As you see the `if` statement is failing and hence the `else` gets executed.

But when I run the if condition manually it shows success

```
$ cat /root/2_need_softwares.txt | grep -v '^#' | grep -iq mongo
$ echo $?
0

$ grep mongo /root/2_need_softwares.txt
mongo
```

Can you please suggest what is wrong with my `if` condition?

I tried the below as well:

```
1. if [[ $(cat $homedir/2_need_softwares.txt | grep -v '^#' | grep -iq mongo) ]]; then

2. if [[ $("cat $homedir/2_need_softwares.txt | grep -v '^#' | grep -iq mongo") ]]; then
```

This is for `bash` and `POSIX` is preferred.

Comment: 1. If you're using `bash` you're already not POSIX. 2. Rather then trying to work out your home directory why not use `$HOME`. 3. What does $homedir evaluate to; are you sure it's `/root`?

Comment: What does $homedir evaluate to; are you sure it's /root -> yes, shared the output of `echo "$homedir"` and even ` if [[ $(cat $HOME/2_need_softwares.txt | grep -v '^#' | grep -iq mongo) ]]; then` returns `false` when it is `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're testing the output of your command sequence rather than the status.

Try this instead

```
#!/bin/sh
if grep -v '^#' "$HOME/2_need_softwares.txt" | grep -iq mongo
then
    echo "Installing mongodb"
else
    echo "skipping mongo"
fi
```